# @ConfigurationProperties or @PropertySource don't work

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-boot

I'm beginner in spring boot and I tried to use @ConfigurationProperties or @PropertySource but I always get a null value

my application.properties file :

```
#application.properties
db.url:https://host.madb
```

my class :

```
@ConfigurationProperties( locations="classpath:/main/resources/application.properties", prefix = "db")
public class TorSeviceImpl {

//if I use @PropertySource("classpath:/main/resources/application.properties") I ll add : @Value("${db.url}")
private String url;
```

but my url variable is always null

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where do you get and use the `TorSeviceImpl`?

Comment: from an other class in the same package.

Comment: No, show us. How do you get it from the context?

Comment: I just try it fron a class with void main method (TorSeviceImpl ts = new TorSeviceImpl(); afer I call ts.getUrl()) or do I need to create an ApplicationSpingContext?

Comment: Yes, you need to get it from the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works now when I get if fron spring context and I added to my AppConfig.java this beans <code>    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }</code>